# MySql Server Trigger Exception Handling

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on Mysql Trigger. 
Basically i am migrating the Sql server code to Mysql server code.

Facing issue into Code
Sql Server Error Handling Code

After Insert Statement Then

```
 If (@@error <> 0)
     Begin
      Raiserror (50002, 11, 1, 'tableName')
      Rollback transaction
      goto Bailout
   End
```

MySql server Code

```
  GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    If RETURNED_SQLSTATE <> 0   # getting Error into IF Condition
    Then
    Signal  SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 50003 11, 1, 'tableName';  #Getting Error in this line
    End if;
```

Goto Statement is not working into Mysql server

Please anyone convert this code into MySQL Code,

> I will be very helpful for me.
>
> **Main thing Mysql trigger not support the Transaction so what is the
>   best way for Error handling into MYsql Trigger.**
>
> Thanks

Aman

Comment: Google for "mysql raise error" and boom, you have your answer. Easy, isn't it?

Comment: You know, a certain level of research is expected here, as this site is no code writing service. I can see none of that in your post. It's not that hard to read the manual for once. It even has plenty of examples!